# Spark Scala Count the Occurrence of Array of strings in the Map Key

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Currently, I have a dataframe which has two fields, name as

```
id1,              id2
Seq[String]      Map[String,(String,Long,Long)]
```

I would like to create another column with name rate, which is the percentage of the number of ids in id1 appear as the key of the map

It seems I was not able to fit a for loop inside the udf, wondering how should I do this?

Comment: are you looking for each of the ids' percentage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Seq.count` and `Map.isDefinedAt` to check the number of keys existing in the Map and then simply wrap it with `udf`:

```
val df = Seq((Seq("a", "b", "c"), Map("a" -> ("x", 1L, 2L), "x" -> ("y", 2L,2L)))).toDF("id1", "id2")

type CustMap = Map[String, (String, Long, Long)]

def percent_in = udf(
    (id1: Seq[String], id2: CustMap) => id1.count(id2.isDefinedAt)/id1.length.toDouble
)

df.withColumn("rate", percent_in($"id1", $"id2")).show
+---------+--------------------+------------------+
|      id1|                 id2|              rate|
+---------+--------------------+------------------+
|[a, b, c]|Map(a -> [x,1,2],...|0.3333333333333333|
+---------+--------------------+------------------+
```

Comment: Hi, the function works fine, however, the way to construct the df is giving me an error shows 'Expression "ExternalMapToCatalyst_value_isNull19" is not an rvalue', did some research but not so many people is having this problem